# Parse Xml String with Joox

Tags: java, xml, joox

How do I parse a Xml `String` with [jOOx](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX)? The parse method accepts String uri, but not Xml `String`.

Comment: Did you try looking into the [test cases](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX/blob/master/jOOX/src/test/java/org/joox/test/JOOXTest.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can do it using the `JOOX` [class](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX/blob/master/jOOX/src/main/java/org/joox/JOOX.java) and a [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html). For example:

```
String xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><root><child attr='attr' /></root>";
StringReader sr = new StringReader( xml );
Match m = JOOX.builder().parse( sr );
```

See the [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) API, which JOOX uses.

You might have to convert the `StringReader` to an `InputSource` or equivalent, but that's a relatively trivial conversion. From the test case:

```
    xmlExampleString = IOUtil.toString(JOOXTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/example.xml"));
    xmlExampleDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlExampleString.getBytes()));
```

In this case, you could write:

```
String xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><root><child attr='attr' /></root>";
StringReader sr = new StringReader( xml );
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( new InputStreamReader( sr ) );
document = builder.parse( bais );
```

That should get you started. Note that there are probably simpler ways to convert a String to an input stream.

Answer (score -1):

In the simplest form it looks like this

```
// Parse the document from string
Document document = $(new StringReader("<?xml version='1.0'?><root><child attr='attr' /></root>")).document();
```

And then do your matching with

```
// Wrap the document with the jOOX API and find root element
Match m = $(document).find("root");
```